# Parse JSON data using Flex / Bison

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm receiveing json data in the following format...

```
{
    "timestamp":55759,
    "sttOutput":
    {
        "time":55759,"words":
        [
            {"startTime":1.81,"duration":0.31,"word":"HEY","score":0.97},
            {"startTime":2.14,"duration":0.31,"word":"WHERE'S","score":0.87},
            {"startTime":2.45,"duration":0.47,"word":"FACEBOOK","score":1.0},
            {"startTime":2.92,"duration":0.57,"word":"TRADING","score":1.0}
        ]
    },
    "kwsOutput":
    {
        "time":55759,"words":
        [
            {"startTime":1.96,"duration":0.19,"word":"FACEBOOK=stock ","score":0.63},
            {"startTime":1.82,"duration":0.55,"word":"WHERE=quest IS FACEBOOK=stock TRADING=stock-act ","score":0.74},
            {"startTime":1.83,"duration":0.55,"word":"WHERE'S=quest FACEBOOK=stock TRADING=stock-act ","score":0.85}
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to parse the data with flex/bison into valid queries that the google calendar API can consume.

Any tips or help on how to do this that demonstrate best practices?

Comment: What "best practices" do you want to adhere to?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, best practices in regards to structuring code architecture for readability and performance.

Answer (score 2):

Flex/bison is rather overkill for JSON, but here's a trivial bison parser to get you started:

```
%token STRING NUMBER TRUE FALSE NULL
%%
object: '{' obj_elems '}' | '{' '}' ;
obj_elems: STRING ':' value | obj_elems ',' STRING ':' value ;
vector: '[' vec_elems ']' | '[' ']' ;
vec_elems: value | vec_elems ',' value ;
value: STRING | NUMBER | TRUE | FALSE | NULL | object | vector ;
```

unpacking into your query API is left as an excercise for the reader...

Comment: You seem to be missing `%start value` (ECMA-404, Section 4, first sentence: "A JSON text is a sequence of tokens formed from Unicode code points that conforms to the JSON value grammar.")